# remove parsed element onclick

Tags: javascript, ajax

I have a parsed xml-file that shows twice the same element. Now I want a button that hides one of them with an onclick-statement. Does anyone know how to do this?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <body>

    <p id="dasa"></p>

    <script>
      var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
      xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
         myFunction(this);
        }
      };
      xhttp.open("GET", "customers.xml", true);
      xhttp.send();

      function myFunction(xml) {
         var xmlDoc = xml.responseXML;
         var x = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("syl");

         document.getElementById("dasa").innerHTML =
         x[0].getAttribute('category') + "<br>";

         document.getElementById("dasa").innerHTML +=
         x[0].getAttribute('category');
      }

      function remove() {
        x[0].removeAttribute('category');
      }
  </script>

  <button onclick="remove()">remove</button>

  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

`x` is undefined in your remove function.

```
function remove() {
   x[0].removeAttribute('category');
}
```

You want something like this:

```
var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
    myFunction(this);
}
};
xhttp.open("GET", "customers.xml", true);
xhttp.send();

var xmlDoc;
var x;
function myFunction(xml) {
xmlDoc = xml.responseXML;
x = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("syl");

document.getElementById("dasa").innerHTML =
x[0].getAttribute('category') + "<br>";

document.getElementById("dasa").innerHTML +=
x[0].getAttribute('category');
}

function remove() {
x[0].removeAttribute('category');
}
```

This will make `x` into a global var set by `myfunction`.

Comment: @JandeVries My code is a working version of yours. You might be manipulating your xml response completely wrong and I won't know since you didn't include that.

Comment: it shows 2 values on the screen, so the parsing is ok, but the button doesn't function.